# What type of relations to choose if I want to link 2 models with one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, model-associations

I have model Message. It may be posted by either Person or Organization from my DB. 
I want to call update.contact, where contact is Organization or Person.

```
class Update < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :contact
```

The decision I like to use is like

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :update, as: :contact
```

But this approach not available in Rails.
Should I use polymorphic association? How to organize the architecture for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `Organization` and `Person` might be two different variants of a same entity (a customer, user, whatever). So, why not create a common parent model for the two of them? Such a parent wouldn't necessarily need a table, and you might just define common methods inside of it. `Update` is more of an action rather than an object, which could be applied to a `Contact` object (typically in its controller). For the `Contact` class, polymorphic association can be used. So you might have:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

# stuff Person and Organization share

end

class Person < Parent

has_one :contact, as: :owner

# Person methods etc.

end

class Organization < Parent

has_one :contact, as: :owner

# Organization stuff

end

class Contact

belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

def update
#...
end

# other stuff for Contact

end
```

Then you can write lines like:

```
Person.first.contact.update
```

or whatever you need to do with your objects.

In case your `Organization` and `Person` don't differ too much, you could just create a table for the parent class, and add the `has_one` etc. in there.